# Login via NSMutableURLRequest and UIWebView

Tags: ios, forms, authentication, http-post, login-script

The website onlinefussballmanager.com (german) is an online browser game, but sadly they don't offer an API, thus I tried to login via their website. I checked the login-form and found out that it just sends a POST-Request to a login script. Then I used [HTMLScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com) to find out more about the  Request:

```
NSString *loginParameters = @"login=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD&LoginButton=Login&js_activated=1";
NSData *loginData = [loginParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *ofmURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://onlinefussballmanager.de/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: ofmURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = loginData;

[self.webview loadRequest:request];
```

As you might imagine it doesn't work, instead it just shows me the homepage without a failed login message. Hope you can <strike>help</strike> teach me. Thanks!